# how to maintain scrollview position while updating collectionview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

Good evening fellow Samaritans
I need the collaboration of the community, I have a collectionview which I update every 3 seconds, but I need it to maintain the scroll position it had before updating every time it is updated, so far I have read several bibliographies and posts but without satisfactory results, Could someone help me, I would appreciate it, greetings

my viewmodels

```
public class MesasAbiertasViewModels : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region variables

        double valorX = 0;

        double valorY = 0;

        public double ValorX
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref valorX, value);

            }
            get
            {
                return valorX;
            }


        }

        public double ValorY
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref valorY, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return valorY;
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<CabeceraComandaModels> lista_mesas;
        List<MesaModel> mesas_ocupadas { set; get; } = new List<MesaModel>();

        List<ConfigurarModels> list_config { set; get; } = new List<ConfigurarModels>();

        Timer tiempo { set; get; } = new Timer();

        DataServiceMesasAbiertas ds_ma;

        DataServiceAbrirMesaView ds_abrir_mesa;

        DataServicePedidosView _dspedidos;

        DataServiceConfigurarPDA _dspda;

        #endregion

        #region propiedades publicas
        public ObservableCollection<CabeceraComandaModels> Lista_Mesas
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref lista_mesas, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return lista_mesas;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public MesasAbiertasViewModels(INavigation nav)
        {
            Navigation = nav;

            ds_ma = new DataServiceMesasAbiertas();

            _dspedidos = new DataServicePedidosView();

            ds_abrir_mesa = new DataServiceAbrirMesaView();

            _dspda = new DataServiceConfigurarPDA();

            list_config = _dspda.ObtenerTodosConfiguracion();

            IniciarActualizacion();

            
        }
        #endregion


        #region Funciones
        public async Task Volver()
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        public void IniciarActualizacion()
        {

            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);


            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                CargarListaMesas();

            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);





        }


        private bool MesaOcupada(int mesa, List<MesaModel> ListaP)
        {
            bool ocupada = false;

            foreach (var items in ListaP)
            {
                if (items.Mesa == mesa)
                {
                    ocupada = true;
                }
            }
            return ocupada;
        }

        public async  void CargarListaMesas()
        {
            try
            {
                Lista_Mesas = new ObservableCollection<CabeceraComandaModels>(ds_ma.ObtenerComandasCab());

                //luego cargamos la lista de mesas ocupadas en ese momento.
                mesas_ocupadas.Clear();

                mesas_ocupadas = ds_ma.ObtenerMesasAbiertas();

                bool ocupada;


                foreach (var items_mesas in Lista_Mesas)
                {
                    ocupada = MesaOcupada(items_mesas.Mesa, mesas_ocupadas);

                    if (items_mesas.Total_condto > 0)
                    {
                        items_mesas.Total = items_mesas.Total_condto;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items_mesas.Total = items_mesas.Total_coniva;
                    }


                    if (ocupada)
                    {
                        items_mesas.Esta_abierta = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items_mesas.Esta_abierta = 0;
                    }





                }

            }
            catch(Exception mi)
            {

                await DisplayAlert("Error", mi.Message, "OK");
            
            }
           
           





        }

        public async Task AbrirMesa(CabeceraComandaModels pcab)
        {

            UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Abriendo Mesas..");

            await Task.Delay(300);

            //obtenemos los datos del modelo con los datos de terminal y numero de pda

            ConfigurarModels modelo = new ConfigurarModels();

            if (list_config != null && list_config.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    modelo = list_config[0];

                    int resultado = ds_abrir_mesa.AbrirMesaSP(pcab.Mesa, Convert.ToInt32(modelo.Terminal));

                    if (resultado == 1) //es porque el proceso de insercion en mesas abiertas fue correcto
                    {

                        //variable para almacenar la lista de articulos de esa comanda abierta
                        List<ArticulosModels> lista_articulos = new List<ArticulosModels>();
                        lista_articulos = _dspedidos.ObtenerArticulosComandasDetalles(pcab.Id_comanda);
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PedidosView(pcab.Mesa.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(modelo.Terminal), 0, lista_articulos, 0));

                    }
                    else if (resultado == 2) //mesa abierta por otro terminal
                    {
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                        await DisplayAlert(MensajesTPV.RegistrosMesaExistenteEncabezado, MensajesTPV.RegistrosMesaExistenteCuerpo, MensajesTPV.OK);

                    }
                    else if (resultado == 0)
                    {
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                        await DisplayAlert(MensajesTPV.RegistrosMesaExistenteEncabezado, MensajesTPV.RegistrosMesaExistenteCuerpo, MensajesTPV.OK);

                    }


                }
                catch
                {
                    await DisplayAlert(MensajesTPV.ErrorConexionEncabezado, MensajesTPV.ErrorConexionCuerpo, MensajesTPV.OK);

                }
                finally
                {
                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No existe una configuracion PDA Valida", "OK");
            }





        }








        #endregion

        #region Comandos
        public ICommand VolverCommand => new Command(async () => await Volver());

        public ICommand ActualizarMesas => new Command(CargarListaMesas);

        public ICommand AbrirComanda => new Command<CabeceraComandaModels>(async (x) => await AbrirMesa(x));
        #endregion



    }
}
```

My Views

```
            <Grid x:Name="contenedorprincipal" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10"  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />


                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="42"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Text="&#10094;" 
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           TextColor="White"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                           Padding="0,5,0,0"
                           Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           Command="{Binding VolverCommand}"
                   
                    />

                <Label Text="Mesas Abiertas" 
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Padding="0,5,0,0"
                           Margin="0,5,0,0"                       
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="WhiteSmoke" 
                           
                   />

                <Frame Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   BorderColor="Black"                                                               
                   CornerRadius="5" 
                   x:Name="frmresultados"
                   Padding="5"
                                         
                   >

                    <CollectionView x:Name="lstpedidos" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Lista_Mesas}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                            
                                  
                                  >
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout  ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Vertical"  />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Frame BackgroundColor="#1c1c1c" CornerRadius="13" Padding="5" x:Name="frmesas"  >
                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AbrirComanda,Source={x:Reference lstpedidos}}"
                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                              >

                                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="35" ColumnDefinitions="50,30,30,50,*"
                                           ColumnSpacing="10"
                                           RowSpacing="5"
                                           Padding="0"
                                           Margin="2,0,5,5"
                                          
                                         
                                      >

                                        <Label
                                            x:Name="lblmesa"
                                                       Text="{Binding Mesa,StringFormat='{0}'}"
                                                       TextColor="White"                                                           
                                                       FontSize="20" 
                                                       FontAttributes="Bold"                                                           
                                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                                       Margin="2"
                                                       VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                                                       VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                                                       
                                                        >


                                        </Label>

                                        <control:ButtonArticulos
                                                       x:Name="btnestado"                                                              
                                                       BackgroundColor="{Binding Esta_abierta,Converter={StaticResource colorConvertor}}"                                                          
                                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                       CornerRadius="20"
                                                       WidthRequest="40"
                                                       HeightRequest="40"                                            
                                                                                                              
                                                  
                                                       >
                                        </control:ButtonArticulos>

                                        <Image Source="comp_emitido.png"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           IsVisible="{Binding Comprobante,Converter={StaticResource comprobanteConvertor}}"
                                           />

                                        <Label x:Name="lbltotal"
                                           Text="Total:"
                                           TextColor="Yellow"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           FontAttributes="Italic,Bold"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Grid.Column="3"
                                           />


                                        <Label             Text="{Binding Total,StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                                       Grid.Column="4"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       FontAttributes="Italic,Bold"
                                                       TextColor="Yellow"
                                                       FontSize="20"
                                                       Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                            >


                                        </Label>


                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>


                </Frame>

            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example？For specific steps, you can refer to this link: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, I have a view that contains a list of open tables, the view is updated every 5 seconds, when this happens the scroll position is put at the beginning, and I want if I am looking at a table that is at the bottom level when the update maintain the scroll position it had before updating the view. thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `ScrollTo` method when refreshing the Collection View, which can help you navigate to the expected scroll position (`Device.beginininVokeonMainthRead (() =>{{lstpedidos.scrollto (OldScrollPosition);});`). Besides, if you are convenient, I still want to get a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help me reproduce your problem.

Comment: Colegas this code is in the viewmodels or in the class xaml.cs explain better please i am New in xamarins forms

Comment: After my testing, a better suggestion: according to the description in the [Control scrolling in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-8.0#detect-scrolling), you can bind an event to the Scrolled property of the CollectionView, then get the current scroll position in the event and assign it to the 'private double lastScrollPosition;' property in the xaml.cs file. After the collectionView is updated, use the 'ScrollTo' method of the collectionView to navigate the scroll position.